# How to compare two feature classes on one field?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arctoolbox, comparison

I have two feature classes: an old one and a new one that I want to compare.

Both feature classes have the same field structure and have a reference field 'ID' whose values are the same, except in the case of deleted rows or added rows.

To compare, I used the tool 'Feature Compare' using 'ID' as a sort field.
The output text is very useful as both attributes and geometry are compared, but the comparison is done on feature that share the same 'OBJECTID'.

How could I use this tool using 'ID' instead?

Alternatively, I tried to join my feature classes on the attribute 'ID' but the result is not easy to analyse as I want to know every modified, added and deleted features.

Comment: Please check [Richard Fairhurst answer](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/126400/27491) on almost same question. This may help you to go forward.

Comment: Google says http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000004000000, that should do what you want.

Comment: Feature Compare do what I want on the OBJECTID field, and not another field. So, according to Richard Fairhurst, the only way to do that is to script it. Let's go.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A solution is to write a python script/tool to compare on one or several fields, which prints every difference found (field values or shape difference).

Comment: If you add this as your own answer, please describe the tool you've written. Otherwise it's not really an answer.